# Is R Embeddable

Tags: r, embedded

I'm thinking to start learning **R**, but I want to know one thing, Is it embeddable(Windows CE, Palm OS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R can be embedded, and this is documented in the R Extensions manual (see the [manuals](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) page for more).

The [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) classes make it easy to embed R inside C++ applications (at least on Linux / OS X). Windows has (D)COM.

But what probably meant to ask were 'ports of R to embedded devices' and that has come up a few times over the years on the mailing lists starting with the Sharp Zaurus etc.  Windows CE and Palm OS are non-starters due to the differences in the toolchain (as you will find out, even on Windows the MinGW tools need to be used).

Comment: Hum, that's very nice, then I can use a ARM C++ compiler to do it! Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Some people must have a high tolerance for pain.

Answer (score 3):

R has also been used [on the iPhone and Google Android](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e8/devel/09/10/0146.html), if you're looking for a mobile OS.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not on Palm OS.  Plus, most of the interaction is through the console, so typing with the virtual keyboard will be painful.

Comment: But I have a keyboard for it, also there are many of this language types for Palm OS.